# Rails - Complicated sql query with query variables as scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need help with a scope in Rails.

I have the following postgresql query:

```
select
  name,
  coalesce(esp.description, eng.description) Description
from games g
left join 
  (select game_id, description from details where locale = 'en-GB') eng 
  on g.id = eng.game_id
left join
  (select game_id, description from details where locale = 'es-ES')
  esp on g.id = esp.game_id
```

What it does basically is getting the names (from table 'games') and the description (from another table called 'details') of a game, if the description is not available in spanish, it takes it in english.

I leave here both tables:

| Games |
| --- |
| id |
| name |

| Details |
| --- |
| locale |
| description |
| game_id |

You can test the query I mentioned before here with two premade games (one has spanish translation and the other doesn't):
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=381eb932e859dcfa9105d5d79a2c9c63

I would like to get the same result as a scope when retrieving the games in rails.

When I try:

```
scope :filter_by_description,
      -> {
        order("description, coalesce(currnt.locale, fallbck.locale) Locale FROM custom_apps c
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM custom_app_details WHERE locale = 'de-DE') currnt on c.id = currnt.custom_app_id
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM custom_app_details WHERE locale = 'en-GB') fallbck on c.id = fallbck.custom_app_id")
      }
```

I just get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeReference at /games
Query method called with non-attribute argument(s): "order("description, coalesce(currnt.locale, fallbck.locale) Locale FROM custom_apps c LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM custom_app_details WHERE locale = 'de-DE') currnt on c.id = currnt.custom_app_id LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM custom_app_details WHERE locale = 'en-GB') fallbck on c.id = fallbck.custom_app_id")"
```

Comment: Please tell us what RDBMS you are using and provide an example of the schema, data and an expected result. This should preferably be code that we can actually run and tinker with.

Comment: But this definately looks like something that should be done with an outer lateral join. LEFT JOIN will limit the rows in the result so you'll only get the rows with both currnt and a fallback.

Comment: @max I updated the question, tell me if I can provide something more usefull.

Comment: This schema does not actually work/make sense. If a game has multiple localized descriptions you would have a `game_id` foreign key column on the details table. As it stands now each game can only have a relation to a single detail. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association. You need to get the basics sorted out before you can approach this problem.

Comment: @max updated both tables and link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is by two lateral subqueries:

```ruby
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :details

  # Gets games with a localized description
  # @param [String] preferred - the preferred locale for the description
  # @param [String] fallback  - the fallback locale for the description
  # @return [ActiveRecord::Relation]
  def self.with_localized_description(preferred: 'es-ES', fallback: 'en-GB')
    # This is the subquery we want to run for each row on the games table
    subquery = Detail.select(:description)
                     .where(Detail.arel_table[:game_id].eq(arel_table[:id]))
                     .limit(1)
    select(
      arel_table[Arel.star],
      # Feel free to use whatever alias you want
      'COALESCE(preferred_locale.description, fallback_locale.description) AS description'
    )
      .outer_lateral_joins(subquery.where(locale: preferred), name: 'preferred_locale')
      .outer_lateral_joins(subquery.where(locale: fallback), name: 'fallback_locale')
  end

  # @param [Arel::SelectCore]  - subquery  
  # @param [String] name       - the alias used for this table
  # @return [ActiveRecord::Relation]
  def self.outer_lateral_joins(subquery, name: '')
     # Rails doesn't have a decent way to write LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL - this is kind of hacky but works
    joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (#{subquery.to_sql}) #{name} ON true")
  end
end
```

The easiest way to describe this is that its like a SQL foreach loop. Each lateral join is telling Postgres to get a single row from the details table for each row on the games table.

Since this is a lateral join you can use `preferred_locale` and `fallback_locale` in the group, order or whatever clause you want just like if you were dealing with a column on the games table. Postgres also lets you use selected columns in the order clause.

For example:

```
Game.with_localized_description.order('fallback_locale.description')
Game.with_localized_description.order(:description)
```

ActiveRecord also makes any aliased columns in the select available as attributes on the records:

```
irb(main):047:0> mario = Game.with_localized_description.find_by(name: 'Mario Cart')
  Game Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "games".*, COALESCE(preferred_locale.description, fallback_locale.description) AS description FROM "games" LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (SELECT * FROM "details" WHERE "details"."game_id" = "games"."id" AND "details"."locale" = 'es-ES' LIMIT 1) preferred_locale ON true LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (SELECT * FROM "details" WHERE "details"."game_id" = "games"."id" AND "details"."locale" = 'en-GB' LIMIT 1) fallback_locale ON true WHERE "games"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "Mario Cart"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=>
#<Game:0x00007fec80133700
...
irb(main):048:0> mario.description
=> "Un buen juego de carreras." 
irb(main):049:0> Game.with_localized_description.order(:description)
  Game Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "games".*, COALESCE(preferred_locale.description, fallback_locale.description) AS description FROM "games" LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (SELECT * FROM "details" WHERE "details"."game_id" = "games"."id" AND "details"."locale" = 'es-ES' LIMIT 1) preferred_locale ON true LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (SELECT * FROM "details" WHERE "details"."game_id" = "games"."id" AND "details"."locale" = 'en-GB' LIMIT 1) fallback_locale ON true ORDER BY "description" ASC
=>
[#<Game:0x000056162a59a3d0
  id: 1,
  name: "Mario Cart",
  created_at: Wed, 23 Mar 2022 12:11:41.658592000 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Wed, 23 Mar 2022 12:11:41.658592000 UTC +00:00>]
```

This method isn't written as a "scope" since the scope method is just syntactic sugar for writing class methods. Jamming this code into a lambda would just ruin the readibility of the code.

Comment: Note that you should be careful if the locale names come from the parameters as they are inserted directly into the query. Use a whitelist.